# Subscript out of range: '0' after execution of stored procedure (asp-classic)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp-classic

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
USE [RK]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PRC_THEKE_FRAGE_KOMPLETTIERUNG_SELECT] @sgi nvarchar(8), @is_nll bit
AS

if @is_nll = 1

select distinct (s.Ort + ' ' + s.Standort + ' ' + s.Strasse) as place
, ROUND(cast(sum(sort.fragenstatus) as real)/cast(sum(sort1.FragenStatus) as real) *100,0) as prozent
from Standorte s
left join LLThekeStamm stamm on s.S_ID = stamm.S_ID
left join LLFragenStandort sort on stamm.LLT_ID = sort.LLT_ID
left join LLThekeFragen tf on sort.FragenId = tf.FragenID
left join LLFragenStandort sort1 on stamm.LLT_ID = sort.LLT_ID and sort1.FragenStatus = 1
where ISNULL(tf.Aktiv, '') = 1 AND s.NLL_SGI = @sgi
group by (s.Ort + ' ' + s.Standort + ' ' + s.Strasse)

else

select distinct (s.Ort + ' ' + s.Standort + ' ' + s.Strasse) as place
, ROUND(cast(sum(sort.fragenstatus) as real)/cast(sum(sort1.FragenStatus) as real) *100,0) as prozent
from Standorte s
left join LLThekeStamm stamm on s.S_ID = stamm.S_ID
left join LLFragenStandort sort on stamm.LLT_ID = sort.LLT_ID
left join LLThekeFragen tf on sort.FragenId = tf.FragenID
left join LLFragenStandort sort1 on stamm.LLT_ID = sort.LLT_ID and sort1.FragenStatus = 1
where ISNULL(tf.Aktiv, '') = 1
group by (s.Ort + ' ' + s.Standort + ' ' + s.Strasse)
```

Just to clarify: It `might` doesn't even matter what the output of this SP is, but just to show that there is a output, I'll attach something for you:

[image]

As you can see, the correct alias are set (namend `place` and `prozent`).

In my `ASP-classic`-part, I'm calling this SP. Have a look at this:

```vb
sub getLocationPercentages()
'open DB connection
conn.open "something"

dim array_prozente()

'counter-variable 
p1 = 0

SQL = "EXEC PRC_THEKE_FRAGE_KOMPLETTIERUNG_SELECT '" & session("sgi") & "',1"

set rs2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs2.open SQL,conn,1,3
redim array_prozente(rs2.RecordCount,1)

'fill array with expected values
do while not rs2.EOF
    array_prozente(p1, 0) = rs2("place") ' <-- this is where the error points at
    array_prozente(p1, 1) = rs2("prozent")
    p1 = p1 + 1
    rs2.MoveNext
loop

rs2.close()
conn.close()

end sub
```

This ends up in this error-message:

> Subscript out of range: '0'

Printing the SQL-String however shows the correct syntax. Copying this output to my Query-window results in the correct values beeing shown.

In my view, I'm trying to access it like this:

```vb
<% for i = 0 to p1 %>
    <% if array_prozente(i, 0) > "" then %>
        <tr><td><%= array_prozente(i, 0) %></td><td><%= array_prozente(i, 1) %></td></tr>
    <% end if %>
<% next %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Short statement**

Simple SQL-queries are working as intended, even with `recordcount`. This just occures (for now) when working with SP.

Comment: What is the value of rs2.RecordCount?

Comment: You could use rs2.GetRows to populate the array. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getrows-method-ado

Comment: RecordCount displays `-1` for some reason

Comment: Yeah recordcount has some special requirements about the cursor type. Try GetRows method.

Comment: Can you please provide an example code? I'm completly new to asp-classic. I tried to adapt that from msdn, but that ended with type-mismatches. So I shouldn't populate the array in the way I'm doing it right now?

Comment: Why are you still trying to populate the array this way? - Related: [passing a multidimensional array from classic asp to javascript (ajax)](//stackoverflow.com/q/42766923)

Comment: @Lankymart no duplicate. simple SQL-queries are working as intended. It seems like this `-1` only occures in combination with stored procedures.

Comment: @DasSaffe That's because you are using the wrong cursor values and method to return the `ADODB.Recordset` object. If you used `ADODB.Command` which is used for parameterised queries *(also fixing your obvious SQL Injection vulnerability)* you wouldn't have this problem. You also should have `SET NOCOUNT ON;` in your stored procedure to stop ADODB seeing result counts as closed RecordSets. Might be useful - [Using Stored Procedure in Classical ASP .. execute and get results](//stackoverflow.com/a/21944948)

Comment: I'm also a big believer in having `BEGIN ... END` encapsulating the stored procedure body.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the ASP side of things but your procedure has multiple execution paths which can lead to some serious performance problems because of plan caching. The upside in this case is that you can massively simplify your procedure and gain consistent performance. Here is how you could modify your procedure to accommodate both paths.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PRC_THEKE_FRAGE_KOMPLETTIERUNG_SELECT] @sgi nvarchar(8), @is_nll bit
AS

select distinct (s.Ort + ' ' + s.Standort + ' ' + s.Strasse) as place
, ROUND(cast(sum(sort.fragenstatus) as real)/cast(sum(sort1.FragenStatus) as real) *100,0) as prozent
from Standorte s
left join LLThekeStamm stamm on s.S_ID = stamm.S_ID
left join LLFragenStandort sort on stamm.LLT_ID = sort.LLT_ID
left join LLThekeFragen tf on sort.FragenId = tf.FragenID
left join LLFragenStandort sort1 on stamm.LLT_ID = sort.LLT_ID and sort1.FragenStatus = 1
where ISNULL(tf.Aktiv, '') = 1 AND s.NLL_SGI = case when @sgi = 1 then @sgi else s.NLL_SGI end
group by (s.Ort + ' ' + s.Standort + ' ' + s.Strasse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GetRows() because it is more efficient than what you are doing in your first sub.

```
sub getLocationPercentages()
    conn.open "something"

    SQL = "EXEC PRC_THEKE_FRAGE_KOMPLETTIERUNG_SELECT '" & session("sgi") & "',1"

    set rs2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs2.open SQL,conn,1,3

    if not rs2.eof then
        array_prozente = rs2.getRows()    
        rs2.close()

        if isArray(array_prozente) then
            for i = 0 to ubound(array_prozente, 2)
                response.write "<tr><td>"
                response.write array_prozente(0,i)
                response.write "</td><td>"
                response.write array_prozente(1,i)
                response.write "</td></tr>"
            next
        end if
    else
        err.raise 8, "mypage.asp", "Query did not return results."
    end if

    conn.close()    
end sub
```

Comment: this somehow comes close, I think. it isn't displaying the correct values and it is some kind of "misformatted". The percentages are missing

Comment: If that `Session("sgi")` value comes from user input at some point in the process this will be left open to SQL Injection vulnerability.